# Как загрузить или сохранить из файла json в таблицу QTable (Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть файл `trip.json`, к примеру

```
{
    "name": "Hawai",
    "days": 25
}
```

Как из этого файла загрузить/сохранить информацию в/из таблицу `QTableView`?

Answer (score 1):

В `QTableView` вы можете установить для отображения `QAbstractItemModel`(или ее наследника, в вашем случае подойдет - `QStandardItemModel`), соответственно вам нужно создать свою модель - наследника одного из этих классов, ее заполнять из `.json` файла, и отображать в таблице методом `void QTableView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel * model).`

То есть как требуется в лабораторке, так и делается обычно в Qt - логика заполнения-сохранения модели будет в отдельном классе.